# Android Toolbar change

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, roboguice

I got an activity , where i set a toolbar.

**MainActivity.class**

```
@ContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
public class MainActivity extends RoboActionBarActivity {

    @InjectView(R.id.tool_bar)
    Toolbar toolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setToolBar();

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new SplashFragment())
                    .commit();
        } else {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.container, new HomeFragment())
                    .commit();
        }
    }

    private void setToolBar() {
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }
 }
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activities.MainActivity">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
        layout="@layout/tool_bar" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/shadow_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tool_bar"
        android:background="#ad8c22" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/shadow_view"
        tools:context=".activities.MainActivity"
        tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**tool_bar.xml**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorToolBar"
    >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_main_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="5dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/tool_bar_action"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:onClick="toggleSlidingMenu"
            android:src="@mipmap/icon_sliding_menu" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/app_logo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:src="@mipmap/jammboree" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:visibility="gone"/>


        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/app_logo"
            android:padding="5dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/hotlist_bell"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:contentDescription="bell"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="7dp"
                android:src="@mipmap/icon_my_cart" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/hotlist_hot"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignRight="@id/hotlist_bell"
                android:layout_alignTop="@id/hotlist_bell"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_square"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:minWidth="17sp"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:text="2"
                android:textColor="#ffffffff"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/myMoneyInMyPocket"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/hotlist_bell"
                android:text="2000$"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </RelativeLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>


</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

When i go to **HomeFragment.class** everything is ok. Now when I move from **HomeFragment.class** to **InfoFragment.class** i want to change my toolbar.

**InfoFragmnet.class**

```
public class InfoFragment extends RoboFragment {


    @InjectView(R.id.menuItemStores)
    LinearLayout menuItemStores;
    @InjectView(R.id.menuItemInsurance)
    LinearLayout menuItemInsurance;
@InjectView(R.id.menuItemWishlist)
LinearLayout menuItemWishlist;
@InjectView(R.id.menuItemAccount)
LinearLayout menuItemAccount;


public InfoFragment() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_info, container, false);
    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        setupUIElements();
    }
}
```

Here i got blocked and didnt find how to change toolbar and override click events on items from toolbar.

Comment: change your toolbar to what??

Comment: change with other layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change the title of the toolbar, just call `toolbar.setTitle(xxx)`
If you want to change the option menu, update the option menu resource and call `invalidateOptionsMenu();`

Hope this will help you.